# Grails-core project has failing unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I'm trying to do some hacking on the 3.0.x branch of grails-core.  With unmodified sources, many tests are failing, as shown below.  I have also tried this with the v3.1.0.RC1 tag and get similar results.  It was my expectation that all tests would pass for at least the RC tag.

I'm probably doing something wrong, as I am not up to speed on the fineries of gradle. If the test are indeed broken, what would be the best way to just run my own tests that will be going in the grails-core module?

```
paul-> git checkout 3.0.x

Switched to branch '3.0.x'

Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/3.0.x'.

[~/src/Grails/grails-core 3.x (3.0.x) ]

paul-> git pull

Already up-to-date.

[~/src/Grails/grails-core 3.x (3.0.x) ]

paul-> ./gradlew test 

:buildSrc:compileJava UP-TO-DATE

:buildSrc:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE

:buildSrc:processResources UP-TO-DATE

:buildSrc:classes UP-TO-DATE

:buildSrc:jar UP-TO-DATE

:buildSrc:assemble UP-TO-DATE

:buildSrc:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE

:buildSrc:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE

:buildSrc:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE

:buildSrc:testClasses UP-TO-DATE

:buildSrc:test UP-TO-DATE

:buildSrc:check UP-TO-DATE

:buildSrc:build UP-TO-DATE

:grails-async:compileJava UP-TO-DATE

:grails-async:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE

:grails-async:processResources UP-TO-DATE

:grails-async:classes UP-TO-DATE

:grails-async:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE

:grails-async:compileTestGroovy UP-TO-DATE

:grails-async:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE

:grails-async:testClasses UP-TO-DATE

:grails-async:test

:grails-bootstrap:compileJava UP-TO-DATE

:grails-bootstrap:compileGroovy

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0

warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7

Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

1 warning

:grails-bootstrap:processResources

:grails-bootstrap:classes

:grails-bootstrap:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE

:grails-bootstrap:compileTestGroovy

warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7

1 warning

:grails-bootstrap:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE

:grails-bootstrap:testClasses

:grails-bootstrap:test



grails.util.BuildSettingsEnvironmentSpec > Test that environment blocks work in BuildConfig FAILED

    groovy.lang.MissingMethodException at BuildSettingsEnvironmentSpec.groovy:29



org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.maven.MavenPomGeneratorSpec > test generating a pom file using Ivy dependency manager FAILED

    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError at MavenPomGeneratorSpec.groovy:96



org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsRootLoaderSpec > NoClassDefFoundError is not obscured by ClassNotFoundException FAILED

    org.apache.tools.ant.BuildException at GrailsRootLoaderSpec.groovy:72



org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.DependencyManagerConfigurerSpec > Test create ivy dependency manager FAILED

    groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException at DependencyManagerConfigurerSpec.groovy:14



org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.IvyDependencyManagerTests > initializationError FAILED

    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException



org.codehaus.groovy.grails.resolve.IvyExcludeResolverSpec > Test that the IvyExcludeResolver resolves excludes FAILED

    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at IvyExcludeResolverSpec.groovy:28

        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at IvyExcludeResolverSpec.groovy:28



83 tests completed, 6 failed, 1 skipped

:grails-bootstrap:test FAILED



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: Without seeing the details in your test report it is hard to say specifically what is going wrong but if you just want to skip those tests run `./gradlew test -x :grails-bootstrap:test`.

Comment: If you only want to run the tests in `grails-core` then run `./gradlew :grails-core:test`.

Comment: Thank you @JeffScottBrown.  It appears that something got corrupted; a "clean" fixed it up.